# Login details to use Oracle BI publisher desktop

Tags: oracle, report, reporting, bi-publisher

I have installed Oracle 10g database and Oracle 10g developer suite.

I am beginner to use Oracle BI publisher for making reports.

Today i have installed Oracle BI publisher desktop for making reports in ms-word 2007.
when i try to log on in BI Publisher option in ms-word. It ask for username, password & report server.

Should i need to installed the BI Publisher Server to fill up the report server details?

please advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to connect to a BI Publisher Server instance to create new reports unless you have a local XML file of sample data from the Server-side Data Model.

With the Template Builder Install  you should have a good set of samples.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\BI Publisher\BI Publisher Desktop\Template Builder for Word\samples\RTF templates\Balance Letter
```

This Tutorial from the Oracle Technology Network will move you along nicely working with the sample files noted above.

**Creating Report (RTF) Templates with MS Word** (This tutorial shows how to work "off-line" with a Sample Data XML file)

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/bi/bip/tb4word/tbwordbip.htm

For real work you will need access to a fully installed BI EE environment then you can reach the BI Publisher component (XMLPSERVER)

```
Username:  weblogic
Password:  ((PASSWORD))
Report Server:  http://NAME:PORT/xmlpserver
```

For a simple install of BI the URL could be:

```
http://192.168.56.101:7001/xmlpserver
```

Without a corresponding server you cannot pull in the data elements defined against the source.

This tutorial will show you much more about BIP.

**Getting Started with Oracle BI Publisher 11g** (focused on using the Online Report Writer:

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/bi/bip/bip11g/gettingstarted/gettingstarted.htm

Comment: Thanks Novadar. Can u give me exact url where i can download Oracle BI Publisher Enterprise server (Stand Alone)?

Comment: There is a trial edition of only BIP which might be just right for you.  Full BIP is part of the OBI 11g Enterprise installation.   The page you need is here:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bi-publisher/downloads/index.html

Comment: Thanks Novadar for your reply.
Is trial edition used for limited period? In my system also having java environment, Oracle 10g database and OC4J with Oracle 10g developer suite.

Comment: The trial edition has no time restrictions.  It should work just fine in your environment.  Since the footprint is small (2.4GB Disk / 1GB Free RAM) it is actually perfect for learning how to use the tools.

Comment: Hi Novadar, after installation of Oracle BI Publisher trail edition, when i click to BI Publisher to start server, command window appear and exit after 20 seconds. when i click again to Start BI Publisher, command  window exit after 5 seconds.may be some errors are coming in sever window. please advice.

Comment: Hi Novadar, I have checked here: C:\Program Files\Oracle\BI Publisher Trial Edition\bip\server\wls\logs\wlst_20130407155608.log com.oracle.cie.domain.ValidateException: Property "ConfirmUserPassword" of JDBCConnectionPool "bip_datasource" is invalid. The property value is required. at com.oracle.cie.domain.aspect.XBeanConfigAspect.selfValidate(XBeanConfigAspect.ja‌​va:558) . .. ... com.oracle.cie.domain.script.ScriptExecutor - The "JDBC" configuration in your domain is invalid. Try to resolve the issue by reviewing your script..